# Скрипт записи в txt файл

Tags: php

Мне нужно сделать скрипт, который сможет генерировать значение, к примеру от: 76561197960265729, до 76561199003528962.
Сделал циклом for, но при генерации таких больших чисел, просто скрипт загинается..
Вот сам код:

```
$min = "76561197960265729";
$max = "76561199003528962";
$file = date("d-m-y") ."__.txt";
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    $fp = fopen($file, "w");
    for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
        fwrite($fp, $i . "\r\n");
    }
    fclose($fp);
    echo "<a href='" . $file . "' download> Скачать файл </a><br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Используйте библиотеку, например [`BC Math`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.bc.php)

Comment: Никогда не работал с этой библиотекой, можете подсказать, что именно в моем скрипте нужно заменить?

Comment: Хм, вы может не поняли что у меня не получается, то есть мы имеем числа: 1 и 10, и в txt файл мне надо занести числа: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, но когда число идет к примеру миллиард, то скрипт просто ложится..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set_time_limit(1000);


$file='go.txt';
for($i = 0; $i <'1043263233'; $i++) {
$go=rand (79602, 90035);
$go1=rand(28962, 65729);
$text='7656119'.$go.$go1;

file_put_contents($file, $text."\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

}
```

генерирует, система не виснет, по крайне мере повторений не будет)

Comment: Опять выбивает ошибку, сгенерировало 285163, на этом остановилось.

Comment: хз у меня текстовый файл весить  стал 11.8 метра https://ibb.co/9HFnC4r

Comment: можешь увеличить время set_time_limit(1000);

Comment: у тебя больше миллиарда строк(столбец), генерация займет скорее всего больше 1000 секунд, ну и завистит от мощности компа. создай пропорцию 285163 => 1000 sec 1043263233 => x sec   короче много времени будет выполнятся, а куда такая задача генерации чисел?

Comment: Нужно сделать скрипт для лабараторной..